# How to search for compass gait Limit Cycles?

Tags: drake

In compass_gait_limit_cycle.ipynb, I followed the instruction and added five groups of constraints:

```
for t in range(T):
    vars = q[t]
    prog.AddConstraint(swing_foot_height, lb=[0]*nq, ub=[np.inf]*nq, vars=vars)
```

However, I got the error information:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-5cf4d7a05da1> in <module>()
      1 # solve mathematical program with initial guess
      2 solver = SnoptSolver()
----> 3 result = solver.Solve(prog, initial_guess)
      4 
      5 # ensure solution is found
RuntimeError: PyFunctionConstraint: Output must be of .ndim = 1 or 2 (vector) and .size = 4. Got .ndim = 1 and .size = 1 instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you imposed the constraint through

```
prog.AddConstraint(swing_foot_height, lb=[0]*nq, ub=[np.inf]*nq, vars=vars)
```

The dimensionality of the `swing_foot_height` doesn't match with `lb` and `ub`. The constraint you want is
`lb <= swing_foot_height(q[t]) <= ub`. If your `swing_foot_height` returns a numpy array containing the scaled valued swing foot height, then both `lb` and `ub` should be of size 1, namely you should change `lb` and `ub` to `lb=[0], ub=[np.inf]`.